# Get Category Details by just URL_TITLE in EE

Tags: categories, url-title

Is there a way that I can get the Category details in EE by just knowing the category url_title ?

Channel Category tag doesn't provide that facility : http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/category_heading.html

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to look at [Cat2](https://github.com/croxton/cat2) and Low [Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) (if you need to infer category data from a URL segment).

Answer (score 0):

[URL Helper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper) is a better/safer way to handle something like this.

Answer (score -3):

May be not the best way to do it, but this is how I did it.

```
{exp:query sql="
SELECT c.cat_name,c.cat_id, c.cat_description
FROM exp_categories c
WHERE c.cat_url_title = '{segment_3}'
AND c.group_id='2'"}

// You can also use categories tag if you want to get custom fields for the category. 
//{exp:channel:categories show='{cat_id}' style='linear'}
//<p> 
//{category_description}
//</p>
//{/exp:channel:categories}

<p>{cat_description}</p>

{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Is an excellent way, but you could improve it, if you don't mind. Add [this](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) as an alternative, please.

Comment: This is cool plugin @RobsonSobral, thanks , but it give me category info only if they are present in URL, I want something that I can pass the url_title or name of the category and gives me the details. Solved now.

Comment: Note that *passing a segment variable to the query module is not safe* - it will not be sanitized by the module before being executed, so it makes your site vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You're better off writing a custom plugin which does the same thing but also runs `ee()->db->escape_str()` on the value you pass in.